# How to retrieve video thumbnail from an absolute path?

Tags: android, file, video, path, thumbnails

I know this has to be trivial but I just don't find the right resource, I guess.
So all I want to do is retrieving a thumbnail for a video. All I have is the absolute path to the file on the sdcard as a String. So please point me into the right direction.

And believe me, this is embarrassing enough to ask...

Regards,
Steff

Answer (score 0):

Have u used this?

```
String Sdcard_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myVideoThumbnails/";
```

;)

Comment: Hi there and sorry for taking so long to get back to you.
Your solution is not what I need. I save the video to a custom folder on the sd-card without adding it to the MediaGallery. Now I need a method which creates a thumbnail from the actual video file on the fly.

Comment: I guess I'll just wait for Froyo... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html